# Why does an implicit conversion on the constructor require 'this'?

Tags: scala

Consider the following typical Scala 'pimp' code:

```
class PimpedA(a:A){
  def pimp() = "hi"
}
implicit def pimpA(a:A) = new PimpedA(a)

new A(){
  pimp()  //<--- does not compile
}
```

However, changing it to:

```
new A(){
  this.pimp()
}
```

Makes it work.
Shouldn't it be the same to the Scala compiler?

**EDIT** : Is there any solution that can make it work without having to add the `this.`?

Comment: Just to say: the convention is that only methods that have side effects are declared with empty parentheses. Not that it is wrong, but in your case, `def pimp = "hi"` should be enough.

Comment: @LeChe Thanks for the tip. Java habits... :)

Comment: Tell me about it: took me ages to get rid of them... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should give compiler a hint that `pimp()` is not a random function. When you write

```
this.pimp()
```

compiler know there isn't `pimp` function on class `A` so it's an error and before giving up it searches implicit conversion in scope and finds it.

```
pimpA(this).pimp()
```

And when you just call `pimp()` compiler doesn't know what object to pass to the `pimpA(a: A)` implicit function.

#### UPDATE

It is hard to understand what is your goal. I can only suggest to make `PimpedA` a typeclass (`Pimp[T]` in this example).

```
trait Pimp[T] {
  def action(p: T): String
}  

implicit object PimpA extends Pimp[A] {
  override def action(p: A) = "some actions related to A"
}

def pimp[T: Pimp](p: T) = implicitly[Pimp[T]].action(p)

class A {
  val foo = pimp(this)
}

scala> new A foo
res2: String = some actions related to A
```

Comment: My goal is to extend a Java library API to make it more Scala friendly.
In my example, class A would be the Java class, and therefore cannot be changed.
(I've updated my example to make clear I'm not implementing class A)

Comment: @hbatista, understand now. Then Daniel's answer explains exactly why it is not working.

Answer (score 5):

Not at all. For it to work, `pimp` needs to be either an object or an imported member of a value, and it is neither. A class has an "implicit" `import this._`. It has *not* a mechanism that auto-prepends `this` to stuff to see if it compiles.